# Why do not sqlite exclusive transactions respect exclusive on linux?

Tags: linux, sqlite, transactions

I am using sqlcipher 2.1.1/ sqlite 3.7.17 on amd64/ubuntu.

Two processes have open connections to the same database. Both processes can start transactions and the transactions are serialised within the process but may occur concurrently between the two processes. All transactions are exclusive: [ret = sqlite3_exec(db, "begin exclusive transaction", NULL, NULL, NULL);].

What I find on linux (and not so on Windows with sqlite 3.6.22) is that these calls succeed and return with SQLITE_OK even when the other process has done the same previously and not yet issued a commit or rollback, i.e. still supposed to hold an exclusive lock on the database. Hence my entire DB locking strategy in the application has gone haywire.

Is it an sqlcipher/sqlite library build issue I am up against?
Is it my lack of understanding what 'exclusive transaction' means?

Thanks for any hint or help on this in advance,
Beata L

Comment: What file system are you using?

Comment: One of the tests were run on ext4, Ubuntu 12.04.3 64-bit x86.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is after some resolution to my problem too:

I found that changing the locking from "unix" to "unix-dotfile" seems to make inter-process exclusive transactions behave. My best guess so far, and it needs confirming, is that the crypto extension is interfering with the default "unix" DB locking.